# How to insert TreeView into accordion using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have a problem how to insert Threeview which is expandable into Accordion.

This is the code of the accordion:

```
public TitledPane createConnectionsTree(String title) {
    connectionsData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(connectionsList);
    ListView<ConnectionsObject> lv = new ListView<>(connectionsData);

    lv.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<ConnectionsObject>, ListCell<ConnectionsObject>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<ConnectionsObject> call(ListView<ConnectionsObject> p) {
            return new ConnectionsCellFactory();
        }
    });
    AnchorPane content = new AnchorPane();
    content.getChildren().add(lv);
    // add to TitelPane
    TitledPane pane = new TitledPane(title, content);
    return pane;
}
```

This is the treeview code:

```
public void initTree() {
    rootNode.setExpanded(true);

    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        TreeItem<String> empLeaf = new TreeItem<>(employee.getName());
        boolean found = false;

        for (TreeItem<String> depNode : rootNode.getChildren()) {
            if (depNode.getValue().contentEquals(employee.getDepartment())) {
                depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            TreeItem depNode = new TreeItem(employee.getDepartment());
            rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
            depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
        }
    }
    VBox box = new VBox();
    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootNode);
    treeView.setShowRoot(true);
    treeView.setEditable(true);
    box.getChildren().add(treeView);
}
```

**P.S**

I get this result:

[image]

I want when I expand the treeview to expand the slider of the accordion not the slider of the treeview. This is the code that I tested:

```
 public TitledPane createConnectionsList(String title) {

    rootNode.setExpanded(true);
    for (ThreeData conn : connectionsThree) {
        TreeItem<String> empLeaf = new TreeItem<>(conn.getName());
        boolean found = false;
        for (TreeItem<String> depNode : rootNode.getChildren()) {
            if (depNode.getValue().contentEquals(conn.getDepartment())) {
                depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            TreeItem depNode = new TreeItem(conn.getDepartment());
            rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
            depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
        }
    }
    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootNode);
    treeView.setShowRoot(true);
    treeView.setEditable(true);

    AnchorPane content = new AnchorPane();
    // Set aligment - fill the accordion with the three content
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(treeView, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(treeView, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(treeView, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(treeView, 0d);

    content.getChildren().add(treeView);
    // Add to TitelPane
    TitledPane pane = new TitledPane(title, content);
    return pane;
}
```

Comment: What is that trouble? Accordion doesn't track treeView size? Or When you put TreeView into TitledPane, and titledPane into accordion, something is not shown?

Comment: put the Tree into a VBox width property `VBox.setVgrow(tree, Priority.ALWAYS);`

Comment: @Kalaschni I updated the code but with no effect. Maybe I have a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably more obvious when you're designing your GUI in SceneBuilder with FXML.  You need to anchor nodes with an AnchorPane so that they stretch out.  For example:

```
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(aNode, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(aNode, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(aNode, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(aNode, 0d);
```

This will anchor each corner of node aNode to the corners of the AnchorPane.  This is what you get in SceneBuilder when selecting the "Fit to Parent" option on an AnchorPane.

Failing that, just use FXML which will make it much easier to get the GUI you want.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem with the tree stretch but I still have a problem how to implement `VBox.setVgrow(tree, Priority.ALWAYS);` Would you please show me what is the correct way to use it?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  What is wrong with the layout after anchoring the tree view?